# Changing a month entered in like "mARCh" to "March"

Tags: java, substring

Code I have so far:
month = month.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + month.substring(1);
When I type march, it comes out as March, which is what I want. But if I typed in mArCh, how would I make it come out as "March" still?

Comment: Use [`.toLowerCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase--) on the second substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just lower case the remaining month substring

```
month = month.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + month.substring(1).toLowerCase()
```